# Shiny plots from user loaded data

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shinydashboard that I want to allow a user to be able to load an excel file and then generate plots and additional output items.  The problem I am running into is I can load the data:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
       dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "data_file",
            fluidPage(
              titlePanel("Upload_Data_File"),
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                            multiple = TRUE,
                            accept = c(".xlsx"))
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  tableOutput('contents'))
              ),
            DT::dataTableOutput("sample_table"))
    ))))

server <- function(input, output) {
df_products_upload <- reactive({

inFile <- input$file1

if(is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)
file.rename(inFile$datapath,
            paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
})

output$sample_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
df <- df_products_upload()
DT::datatable(df)
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I'd like to do some analysis on this dataframe I can do this inside of the server option:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  data <- df_products_upload() ........ #Some Analysis
  data2, data3.... # Items generated during analysis 
  plot(data2)})
```

and then complete the analysis inside of the output function and create my additional data frames that will eventually be utilized in calls.  But if I want to create multiple output plots that will be generated in the dashboard, is there better efficiency to allow the analysis to be run so future output plots can be generated this way?

```
 output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
     plot(data3) })
```

Currently I can only get it work by duplicating the analysis for all outputs in the server which is very inefficient.

```
 output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
   data <- df_products_upload() ........ #Some Analysis
   data2, data3.... # Items generated during analysis 
   plot(data3)})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that what you need is

```
data<-reactive({
    data <- df_products_upload() ........ #Some Analysis
    data #data should be a vector, list or whatever containg all the itmes
    })
```

and then

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
 plot(data()[1]) 
})

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
 plot(data()[2]) 
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me a little bit to figure out with my exactly scenario but I got it working!